# Javascript adding cookie value as object, unlike PHP that adds it

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

This is my code:

```
<?php
    $cookie = [
            'url' => (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : null),
            'landing_page' => "//{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}",
            'date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
        ];

        setcookie("mycookie_".rand(1,1000), json_encode($cookie), time() + (86400 * 30), "/");

?>
<script>    
var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1);

setcookie("first_interaction"+random,<?=json_encode($cookie)?>,365)
</script>
```

The problem is how the value of "json_encode($cookie)" is added as a cookie value, see below:

Value when adding the cookie in Javascript:

```
 [object Object]
```

Value when adding the cookie in PHP:

```
%7B%22url%22%3Anull%2C%22landing_page%22%3A%22%5C%2F%5C%2Fwww.site.com%5C%2FcookieTest.php%3Ftest%3Dtest%22%2C%22date%22%3A%222018-07-05+17%3A33%3A34%22%7D
```

I'd like JS to add the cookie value the same as PHP ... any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

```
setcookie("first_interaction"+random,<?=json_encode($cookie)?>,365)
```

The issue here is that you are putting raw json into that method call.  When javascript is parsed by the browser, it will turn it into a real object, which is most likely why you are seeing `[object Object]`.

I would suggest putting single quotes around the value, so javascript will leave it as a string.

```
setcookie("first_interaction"+random,'<?=json_encode($cookie)?>',365)
```